# Issue with DataGrid column wrapping and widths

Tags: asp.net, css, data-binding, datagrid

I have an asp.net datagrid, one column displays the address. Sometimes the length of the address is longer than can be displayed, so I want to just truncate the display.

I have tried setting , but this just makes the address column wider to accommodate the longer text (it also effect the width of the preceding column, Name).

Is there a way to tell the column not to wrap or extend past the set column width (set in the CSS) or will I need to limit the length of the string before binding it to the datagrid?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your looking for the CSS property [overflow](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp).

You should apply that to your cell so you will need to set the `CssClass` on the `ItemStyle` to a style with overflow defined.

I prefer to not use the overflow when possible and try to truncate and add a `...` to the end to indicate text is missing or else it could cut off after a space and no one would know that any text was missing.

Answer (score 1):

Use a TemplateColumn, and do something like the following in the ItemTemplate:

```
<asp:TemplateColumn>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <div style="width:200px;overflow:hidden;">
          <%#Eval("<COLUMN NAME>")%>
      </div>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```